# How to solve apex.ajax.clob error in Oracle 18c APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle18c

I am trying to show pins in my map control and I was using the following code in old theme 4.2 and it was working fine. But with new APEX theme, I am getting `apex.ajax.clob` is not a constructor error

```
function refreshMap() 
{
  var gData;
  var clob_ob = new apex.ajax.clob
  (  
function()
{
  var rs = p.readyState  
  if(rs == 4)
  {
    gData = p.responseText;
    if(gData.length == 0)
    {
      alert("No task found.");
      return;
    }
    if(gData=='-1')
    {
      alert("Data too large to be displayed. Filter task by type or select smaller date range.");
      return;
    }
  }
  if(gData)
  {
    var actArray = gData.split("~#~");
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for(var i=0; i < actArray.length; i++) 
    {
      acct = ""+actArray[i];
      var colArray = acct.split("~@~");
      var repStatus = colArray[5];
      var link = '<b><u><a href="'+colArray[7]+'">'+colArray[2]+'</a></u></b>';
      var html = '<table><tr><td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 175%;">'+colArray[3]+'</td></tr></table><table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><b>Task # : </b>&nbsp;</td><td>'+link+'</td></tr><tr><td align="left"><b>Subject : </b>&nbsp;</td><td>'+colArray[4]+'</td></tr><tr><td align="left"><b>Status :   </b>&nbsp;</td><td>'+repStatus+'</td></tr></table>';
      var newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(colArray[0], colArray[1]),
          map: map,
          //title: html,
          icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|'+colArray[8]
      });

      newmarker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: html
          });

      google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', function() {
          this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
      });

      marker.push(newmarker);
                bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(colArray[0], colArray[1]));
    } 
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
});  
clob_ob._get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`apex.ajax.clob` was deprecated and moved to `legacy_18.js` (at least in 18.2). To follow the example you have to include `/i/libraries/apex/legacy_18.js`. This can be done on a page-by-page basis in the Javascript -> File URLs box.

Comment: If you are using it all over the place, there is option in the User Interface -> User Interface Details -> JavaScript. There you can check the box to Include Deprecated or Desupported JavaScript Functions for "Pre 18.1" and "18.x".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old post, but I found it while experience the same issue and looking for solution. As this was one of the first links to appear for me on Google, after finding the solution, I decided to share a code here for future references.

You'll need to adjust this code to your situation, so please take it as example, how to approach this issue without relying on the legacy javascript.

In this example I've a CLOB which contains HTML source (accepting few parameters) and I need to display it in region on page load.

First you create a AJAX Callback process (let's call this process **HTML**)

```
DECLARE
  l_clob        CLOB;
  l_file        BLOB;
  l_dest_offset PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_src_offset  PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_lang_ctx    PLS_INTEGER := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
  l_blob_warn   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

  -- Get clob
  l_clob := functionReturningClob(i_code => :P1_CODE, i_type => :P1_TYPE);

  -- Create blob
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_file, true);
  DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB(l_file, l_clob, dbms_lob.lobmaxsize, l_dest_offset, l_src_offset, dbms_lob.default_csid, l_lang_ctx, l_blob_warn);

  -- Download blob
  OWA_UTIL.MIME_HEADER('text/html', false);
  HTP.P('Content-Length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(l_file));
  HTP.P('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="content.html"');
  OWA_UTIL.HTTP_HEADER_CLOSE();
  WPG_DOCLOAD.DOWNLOAD_FILE(l_file);

END;
```

With this out of the way, I can call this on demand when I want. For my purposes I've got on my page - Javascript Execute when Page Loads, which contains following code.

```
// Start the process called HTML and add the following page items as parameter
var p = apex.server.process('HTML', {
  pageItems:['P1_CODE', 'P1_TYPE']
}, {
  dataType: 'html'
});

// When the process is done, replace the region HTML with the downloaded HTML source
// Also - the region on the page has the "region" as its static ID
p.done(function(data) {
  $('#region').html(data);
});
```

This should give you enough information to make your own adjustments and make it work.